# Is there any efficient way to keep a thread, which has ActionListener in it's run method, alive until a click event has occured?

Tags: java, multithreading, actionlistener

```
      boolean flag = true;
      public void run(){
      // some code
         loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             flag = false; 
             // Some code
         }
      }); 

      while(flag){}
      }
```

I am using while loop till the actionListener is invoked which I think is silly perhaps. Please let me know if this can be done in more efficient way.

Comment: Why do you need the thread in the first place?

Comment: actionPerformed will be called from UIThread. There is no need to keep your thread alive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need a Thread for the Listener itself, the Java UI Thread calls your Listener for you.

However if you want your response to the event non-blocking do the following:

```
// no need for a second thread here
loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         // If you dont want to block the UI Thread make a new Thread here
         new Thread(YOUR_RUNNABLE).start();
     }
}
```

[Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156949/main-thread-vs-ui-thread-in-java)

Comment: Thanks @Nick for valuable information! I just learned couple of java UI concepts.