# What is this odd delay with JFrame Components

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, java-8

**EDIT:** Although I have never used (or even known about) `SwingUtilities.InvokeLater()` before today, implementing it did not solve the problem. The 1-second delay between the visibility of the JFrame and the appearance of the JLabel remains with the following, updated code.

```
public class DelayTest {

public static void main(String [] args) {
    new DelayTest();
}

public DelayTest() {
     SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
        {
          public void run()
          {
              long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Demo");
            Container content = frame.getContentPane();

            //sizing
            Dimension dimm = new Dimension(500, 200);
            frame.setPreferredSize(dimm);
            frame.setResizable(false);

            //content
            content.add(new JLabel("Hello, Delayed World"));
            System.out.println("Added Label at: " + 
                    (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " Milliseconds");

            //end
            frame.pack();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            System.out.println("Finished execution at: " + 
                    (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " Milliseconds");
          }
        });
    }
}
```

I have, so far, done the following to try to resolve the error:

- Updated my Computer (Mac OS X 10.11.6)
- Updated Java (java version "1.8.0_111")
- Erased and Re-Installed Eclipse (Java Neon.2)
- Exported jar, just to see if the problem existed outside Eclipse
- Tested using SwingUtilities.InvokeLater() as seen above (Hopefully I used it correctly)

I restarted several times throughout the process but nothing seemed to fix it.  I'm hoping you can either help me find the error in my code that is delaying the Label (which I don't think exists,) or verify that my code works on your computer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Main Thread vs. UI Thread in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156949/main-thread-vs-ui-thread-in-java)

Comment: Well, to start with, you're not created/shown the frame within the context of the EDT, so there could be a delay in the EDT becoming available and processing the required events. It may not fix the issue entrily, but I'd suggest wrapping the code in `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` and try again.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I appreciate the advice, but it does not seem to have worked in this case, assuming I'm using the method correctly (see my update above.)  Still, I'm glad to know about this so I can start implementing it in my projects.

Comment: Did you try calling `frame.validate();` right before `frame.setVisible(true);`?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, my problem was instantly fixed by specifying a `LayoutManager` for the `content` Container. I'm now assuming it to be a strange Java bug, perhaps only on Mac.  The following code resolves my issue:

```
public class DelayTest {

public static void main(String [] args) {
    new DelayTest();
}

public DelayTest() {
     SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
        {
          public void run()
          {
              //long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Demo");
            Container content = frame.getContentPane();

            //NEW CODE
            content.setLayout(new BoxLayout(content, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
            //END NEW CODE

            //sizing
            Dimension dimm = new Dimension(500, 200);
            frame.setPreferredSize(dimm);
            frame.setResizable(false);

            //content
            content.add(new JLabel("Hello, Delayed World"));

            //end
            frame.pack();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);

          }
        });
    }
}
```

Having a GUI that does not use one Layout Manager or another is almost entirely pointless, which explains why I've never seen this problem before.

TL;DR: Always use a `LayoutManager` (and `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`, apparently) even if you only need to display one component in the window.

Comment: Funny I tried with a `BorderLayout` and still got the same results (delayed JLabel).  However, if you see my answer below the call to `frame.setSize(dimm);` over the call to `frame.setPreferredSize(dimm)` works as well.

Comment: The issue definitely seems to be related to `setPreferredSize`, removing that one line seems to make it work just fine.  Since the frame uses a `BorderLayout` by default, I'd say you're seeing a side effect, not the solution - IMHO

Answer (score 0):

Remove the call to `frame.setPreferredSize(dimm);` and after `frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);` add the following:

```
frame.setSize(dimm);
```

Comment: I wouldn't put `setSize` after `setLocationRelativeTo`, `setLocationRelativeTo` will rely on the size of the frame to position it correctly ;), but `setSize` definitely has an effect

Comment: Agreed.  Calling `setSize` after `setLocationRelativeTo` causes the JFrame to render off-center but everything works as expected if you reverse the order. 

What is the etiquette here?  Should I update my own answer or wait to select one of yours once it's correct?  I don't think I get points for answering my own question anyway :)