# repaint for javax not work

Tags: java, swing, repaint, event-dispatch-thread

Here is my Code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main {
// code main
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(460, 500);
    frame.setTitle("Circles generator");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            frame.setVisible(true);

        }

    });

    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter n:");
    CustomComponents0 component = new CustomComponents0();
    frame.add(component);
    frame.getContentPane().validate();
        System.out.println("work before");
    frame.getContentPane().repaint();
        System.out.println("work");

    frame.getContentPane().repaint();
        System.out.println("work after");

}

// why is not JComponent
static class CustomComponents0 extends JLabel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 100);

    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(300, 200);

    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        System.out.println("paint");
        int margin = 10;
        Dimension dim = getSize();
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(margin, margin, dim.width - margin * 2, dim.height - margin * 2);

    }

}
```

here is the code and I want run repaint before work and run repaint after work. 
When I run it, it should print

```
work before
paint
work
paint
work after
```

but there are only one paint and it's after work, Why is that happen? How can I fix that?

Thanks.

Comment: Why? What needs fixing? Why worry about precisely when and if a painting occurs? Understand that you can only request a painting not require it (for the most part).

Comment: That is not the way painting works. A "repaint()" is just a request to paint a component. When you have two requests in a row, they are consolidated into a single request. What is the point of this logic? If you need a time lapse between painting then you can use a `Swing Timer`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You [must](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7158505/230513) construct and manipulate Swing GUI objects *only* on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). Because your program is incorrectly synchronized, any result is possible. It will depend in part on how far the [initial thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) gets before starting the [`EventQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html). Moreover, `println()` itself [may be synchronized](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9459657/230513), and "events being posted to the `EventQueue` can be coalesced."

The variation below reliably shows the following output because events are dispatched "In the same order as they are enqueued." Note in particular how the calls to `repaint()` are coalesced. While this approach is illustrative, it is needlessly cumbersome for your likely goal. Instead, use [`javax.swing.Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to pace animation as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A230513%20javax.swing.Timer).

Console:

```
paint
work before
work
work after
paint
```

Code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

/** @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44212328/230513 */
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setTitle("Circles generator");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            CustomComponent component = new CustomComponent();
            frame.add(component);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> { System.out.println("work before"); });
            EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> { frame.repaint(); });
            EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> { System.out.println("work"); });
            EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> { frame.repaint(); });
            EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> { System.out.println("work after"); });
        });
    }

    static class CustomComponent extends JLabel {

        private static final int N = 10;

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(300, 200);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            System.out.println("paint");
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillRect(N, N, getWidth() - N * 2, getHeight() - N * 2);
        }
    }
}
```