# JFreeChart doesen't work and block my code

Tags: java, eclipse, jfreechart

```
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFrame;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.data.general.DefaultPieDataset;

public class JfreeChartPie {

    System.out.println("piechart");

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("piechart");
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // create a dataset...
        DefaultPieDataset dataset = new DefaultPieDataset();
        dataset.setValue("Category 1", 43.2);
        dataset.setValue("Category 2", 27.9);
        dataset.setValue("Category 3", 79.5);
        // create a chart...
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart(
        "Sample Pie Chart",
        dataset,
        true,
        // legend?
        true,
        // tooltips?
        false
        // URLs?
        );
        // create and display a frame...
        ChartFrame frame = new ChartFrame("First", chart);
        //frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I run debian 9 gnu linux and eclipse 2018-09
I get from console just the text about jfreechart license, and it seems that it doesen't exute the code.I have got no problems.

Comment: That code doesn't even compile.  Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: @Joe C this is the complete code, and I compiled it.I don't know what do u want,I read your suggestion but I think my post is ok.THanks

Comment: Except for the first (misplaced) call to `println()`, your example runs on my platform. See also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html), which may be critical on your platform.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid such anomalies, verify that you construct and manipulate Swing GUI objects *only* on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). As noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7158505/230513), "A program may *appear* to work correctly, only to fail mysteriously in a different environment." For reference, I've modified your example accordingly.

[image: pie chart]

```
$ javac -cp .:$JFC JFreeChartPie.java && "$JRE" -cp .:$JFC JFreeChartPie
```

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFrame;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.data.general.DefaultPieDataset;

public class JFreeChartPie {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("piechart");
                DefaultPieDataset dataset = new DefaultPieDataset();
                dataset.setValue("Category 1", 43.2);
                dataset.setValue("Category 2", 27.9);
                dataset.setValue("Category 3", 79.5);
                JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart(
                    "Sample Pie Chart", dataset, true, true, false);
                ChartFrame frame = new ChartFrame("Title", chart);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setSize(400, 400);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot.I solved, eclipse started another application.sorry

Comment: Glad you got it sorted, but beware of latent synchronization problems. More above.