# Mac JVM rendering JTabbedPane differences between 1.6 and above

Tags: java, macos, swing, border, jtabbedpane

This is how JTabbedPane renders in Java 1.6:

[image: JTabbedPane rendered perfectly in Java 1.6]

When using Java 1.7 (or 1.8 EA), see the bottom of the tabs getting clipped:

[image: JTabbedPane rendered badly in Java 1.7 and 1.8]

I tried, without any success (or effect) the system properties *-Dcom.apple.macos.smallTabs=true* and *-Dcom.apple.smallTabs=true*.

Any solution or hack for this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. I had this code that was called *before* building the UI in `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` block:

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

...

Font f = new Font(Font.DIALOG, Font.PLAIN, 12);
ArrayList<String> excludes = new ArrayList<String>();
Enumeration itr = UIManager.getDefaults().keys();
while(itr.hasMoreElements()){
    Object o = itr.nextElement();
    if(o instanceof String) {
        String key = (String) o;
        Object value = UIManager.get (key);
        if ((value instanceof javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource)
                && (!excludes.contains(key))){
            UIManager.put (key, f);
        }
    }
}
```

I wanted all UI elements to have uniform Font in my application. When I commented this block, the UI rendering came up as in Java 6. Seems to be a bug in later Java releases.

Answer (score 3):

Running this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11949899/230513), I am unable to reproduce the effect shown on Mac OS X 10.9.2 using Java 7. I suspect you are neglecting to `pack()` the enclosing `Window`, but you might compare your code to the one shown for reference.

[image]

Comment: Your example is running fine for me too. But when I run my [RESTClient tool](http://code.fosshub.com/WizToolsorg-RESTClient/downloads), this is not the case. Yes, I do [use pack()](https://github.com/wiztools/rest-client/blob/master/restclient-ui/src/main/java/org/wiztools/restclient/ui/RESTMain.java) as mentioned by you.

Comment: Also verify that you are constructing the GUI on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html); some APIs have [changed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15979112/230513).

Comment: Found the issue. I use this before initializing the Swing UI: `javax.swing.UIManager.put (key, f);` with custom Font `f`. If I comment out this code, this tab-corruption does not happen.

Comment: This seems plausible. You can update your question or [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188).