# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError Unable to create new native thread

Tags: java, swing, timer, jtable, global-variables

(Working in NetBeans/Java) I use a button to retrieve values from an external source, and everything worked all well and fine with minor issues, then I started encountering a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread` exception

This application writes the external values to a JTable. This external values are public variables in other locations

I know it's bad practice to work with multiple JFrames, but I don't see the point in it to recreate a whole new Java Card or Option Pane/Dialog. I'm also determined to create a work-around to get the thing working.

What could be causing it and how do I fix it?

Here's the code. The exception points to `Timer timer = new Timer();`.

```
String username;
String password;

//...

final Apps.UserManager.NewUser newUser = new Apps.UserManager.NewUser();
newUser.setVisible(true);
newUser.requestFocus();

newUser.suVftrun = 0;

int delay = 10000; // delay for 10 sec.
int period = 1000; // repeat every sec.

do{
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
            int bcol1 = model.getColumnCount();
            int bcol2 = model.getRowCount();

            username = newUser.u2ftrun;
            password = newUser.p2ftrun;

            System.out.println(newUser.u2ftrun);
            System.out.println(newUser.p2ftrun);

            try {
                String tRecord1 = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(bcol1, bcol2);
                if (newUser.suVftrun == 1) {
                    if (!username.equals(null)) {
                        if (!tRecord1.equals(username)) {
                            model.addRow(new Object[]{username, password});
                            this.cancel();
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Same Data");
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("No Data Received!");
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("User hasn't been created yet");
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("No values in table. Trying alternative");
                try {
                    if (newUser.suVftrun == 1) {
                        if (!username.equals(null)) {
                            try {
                                model.addRow(new Object[]{username, password});
                                this.cancel();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                System.out.println("Repeating...");
                            }
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("No Data Received!");
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("User hasn't been created yet");
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }, delay, period);
} while (newUser.isVisible());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a **massive issue**. Wait, that's not big enough:

### A Massive Issue

Better.

You are busy waiting in a `do` loop and spinning up a new `Timer` each time:

```
do {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    //some other stuff
} while (newUser.isVisible());
```

This is causing thousands (millions?) of `Timer` instances to be created, each with its own `Thread`.

1. **never** busy wait
2. don't create thousands of `Timer` instances

Further, you are using the [`java.util.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) not the [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) which means that the eventual action is not executed on the EDT.

This is a violation if the Swing threading policy. Swing objects, except in [rare case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796578/which-swing-component-methods-are-thread-safe), are **not thread safe** and should **only be accessed from the EDT**.

In short; there is very little that *isn't* wrong with this code.

Comment: Haha oops. I just learned something new. Ok, so the dowhile is a brain error, which I now understand. I'm not so clued-up with the javax.swing.Timer class. My coding is based on examples on the interwebs. I removed java.util.Timer and replaced it with javax.swing.Timer, but now the IDE is giving me errors. I guess it's back to javadocs with me... Thanks, for pointing out the coding that's right, though :D