# Sporadic GUI freeze on the (java) application start

Tags: java, swing

we have a strange problem with our GUI after changing to Java 1.7.

Sometimes if the user starts our Application it seems to be freezed, but probably there is just no repaint, because if user tries for example to scroll, changes the window and comes back to application the scroll changes are visible.

And the problem will be solved if the users change to fullscreen.

I tried to search for this problem, but the only thing most related to it was an unanswered question here:

http://www.java-forums.org/awt-swing/31107-intermittent-freeze-javawebstart-swing-app.html

May be anyone of you had the problem and know the solution?

Comment: Please, show code of GUI creation.

Comment: smells like an EDT rule violation

Comment: May be anyone of you had the problem and know the solution? --> (agree with both comments) there aren't Thread Safe methods for Swing APIs in Java7, are removed

Comment: > there aren't Thread Safe methods for Swing APIs in Java7, are removed -> what was removed?

Comment: removed were documentation errors that incorrectly marked some methods as thread-safe ;-) The first step in solving the problem is to make sure _each and every access_ to swing properties (including models!) happens on the EDT.

Comment: btw, if you want to communicate with a commenter, you have to address him/her directly, like f.i. @mKorbel

Comment: `removed were documentation errors that incorrectly marked some methods as thread-safe` - hmmm I can't resist, I think not true about were incorectly marked (talking only and about AWT/Swing APIs), because most of Thread Save methods(many times here discused in last year) valid for Java6(e.g. setText, append), doesn't required EventDispatchThread returns true in Java6,  those methods aren't longer Thread Safe and don't work without invokeLater in Java7, simple example setText (and another methods in marked as Thread Safe) from Runnable#Thread doesn't required invokeLater as notifier for EDT

Comment: @all assume, the former thread safe methods are not thread safe anymore. But why then these freezes occur sporadically?

Comment: @mKorbel _especially_ the textComponent related methods were incorrectly marked as thread safe ;-) And yeah, it has been discussed to death and all those discussions don't matter: documentation rules - whatever isn't marked as thread-safe **now** **must-not** be accessed off the EDT. Bet my soul on the OPs problem being an EDT violation ... and there're exactly **zero** ways around but removing those violations.

Answer (score 1):

The migration to Java 7 may have exposed a latent problem in the original code. Here are some things to look at:

- Some APIs, especially among the text components listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15979112/230513), are no longer marked thread safe in Java 7.
- You can search for EDT violations using one of the approaches cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7787998/230513).
- Resizing the enclosing `Window` generates an automatic `repaint()`; if your updates are otherwise correctly synchronized, you can sequence your own `repaint()` using `invokeLater()`.
- Verify that `setVisible()` is *last* in your initialization, *after* `pack()`.