# javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument$LeafElement contains invalid p0/p1 values

Tags: java, swing

I'll apologize in advance for the lack of specificity on this, but I am unsure how this is being caused.

We have a XMLDocument that extends javax.swing.text.DefaultStyledDocument

If we make rapid undo/redo calls (say, holding ctrl+z or ctrl+shift+z), the AWT EventQueue thread throws an exception:

```
javax.swing.text.BadLocationException: Length must be positive
getText():810, AbstractDocument {javax.swing.text}
getText():135, GlyphView {javax.swing.text}
getSpan():60, GlyphPainter1 {javax.swing.text}
getPreferredSpan():592, GlyphView {javax.swing.text}
getPreferredSpan():732, FlowView$LogicalView {javax.swing.text}
calculateMinorAxisRequirements():233, FlowView {javax.swing.text}
calculateMinorAxisRequirements():724, ParagraphView {javax.swing.text}
checkRequests():935, BoxView {javax.swing.text}
getMinimumSpan():568, BoxView {javax.swing.text}
calculateMinorAxisRequirements():903, BoxView {javax.swing.text}
checkRequests():935, BoxView {javax.swing.text}
setSpanOnAxis():343, BoxView {javax.swing.text}
layout():708, BoxView {javax.swing.text}
setSize():397, BoxView {javax.swing.text}
setSize():1714, BasicTextUI$RootView {javax.swing.plaf.basic}
modelToView():1046, BasicTextUI {javax.swing.plaf.basic}
repaintNewCaret():1311, DefaultCaret {javax.swing.text}
run():1290, DefaultCaret$1 {javax.swing.text}
dispatch():312, InvocationEvent {java.awt.event}
dispatchEventImpl():733, EventQueue {java.awt}
access$200():103, EventQueue {java.awt}
run():694, EventQueue$3 {java.awt}
run():692, EventQueue$3 {java.awt}
doPrivileged():-1, AccessController {java.security}
doIntersectionPrivilege():76, ProtectionDomain$1 {java.security}
dispatchEvent():703, EventQueue {java.awt}
pumpOneEventForFilters():242, EventDispatchThread {java.awt}
pumpEventsForFilter():161, EventDispatchThread {java.awt}
pumpEventsForHierarchy():150, EventDispatchThread {java.awt}
pumpEvents():146, EventDispatchThread {java.awt}
pumpEvents():138, EventDispatchThread {java.awt}
run():91, EventDispatchThread {java.awt}
```

Now, obviously this is being called from the AWT Update thread.

The actual element it's throwing up on is:

```
[4] = {javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument$LeafElement@6621}"LeafElement(content) 223,217\n"
p0 = {javax.swing.text.GapContent$StickyPosition@6652}"223"
p1 = {javax.swing.text.GapContent$StickyPosition@6655}"217"
this$0 = {com.timetra.nms.client.gui.script.editor.document.XmlApiDocument@6211}
parent = {javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument$BranchElement@6585}"BranchElement(paragraph) 191,238\n"
attributes = {javax.swing.text.StyleContext$SmallAttributeSet@6656}"{family=Courier,size=12,foreground=java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=0],}"
this$0 = {com.timetra.nms.client.gui.script.editor.document.XmlApiDocument@6211}
```

(Taken from intelliJ debugger).

as you can see p0 and p1 are incorrect. but also, this element shouldn't be there since the [3] and [5] elements in the array match the range:

```
[3] = {javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument$LeafElement@6620}"LeafElement(content) 215,223\n"
[4] = {javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument$LeafElement@6621}"LeafElement(content) 223,217\n"
[5] = {javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument$LeafElement@6622}"LeafElement(content) 223,237\n"
```

I assume that I'm missing a synchronization, or a SwingUtilities.runLater(...) invocation, but I have no idea where, I've put them everywhere I can think of in the Undo/Redo classes that we use.

Edit:

This is how edits are being added to the UndoManager:

```
public void undoableEditHappened(final UndoableEditEvent ev)
    {
        UndoableEdit edit = ev.getEdit();
        // Include this method to ignore syntax changes
        // To reduce memory consumption, do this check before adding runnable.
        if (edit instanceof AbstractDocument.DefaultDocumentEvent &&
            ((AbstractDocument.DefaultDocumentEvent) edit).getType() ==
              AbstractDocument.DefaultDocumentEvent.EventType.CHANGE)
        {
            return;
        }

        try {
            UndoableEdit temp = ev.getEdit();
            undoManager.addEdit(temp);
            undoAction.updateState();
            redoAction.updateState();
            setChanged(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Edit 2: I found the majority of the issues I saw were caused by a function that is on the invokeLater() runnable which attempts to syntax highlight the text after an undo/redo event. I'm concerned that even though it's on the EventQueue it's not in sync. Is there a priority order or something for the order in which these events are fired?

Comment: Nobody can help you without seeing your code, and I suspect it's way too long to post here.  You will have to set an exception breakpoint and try to catch it in the act.

Comment: I can only get the exception from the AWT EventQueue thread, and that's where I got the information I posted above, there's no other exception thrown.

I know it's a long shot without a distinct testcase, I'm working to see if I can recreate it (I'm working on a massively old piece of code that no-one knows about). 

What I'm looking for is pointers.

Comment: You can try to wrap all the undo/redo calls in the SwingUtilities.invokeLater(). One more point is to check how the UndoableEdits are stored. Do they have copy of DOM structure or references to the structure. Copy is safer

Comment: @StanislavL I'm not sure what you mean, I've added the code for the undoable edit listener.

Comment: You must add the Change events to the UndoManager. In opposite case Document structure is changed but you try to undo with old structure. You can merge multiple UndoableEdits in one see http://java-sl.com/tip_merge_undo_edits.html

Comment: @StanislavL: Can you add this as answer?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct to infer the possibility of incorrect synchronization. The exception may occur on the EDT due to an errant `Document` update on another thread. Some [methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15979112/230513) of certain  text components are *no longer* marked as thread safe in recent Java versions. Look for EDT violations, as suggested in the articles cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7787998/230513). For an initial check, `CheckThreadViolationRepaintManager` is the easier approach.

Comment: I used the CheckThreadViolationRepaintManager method first, however this didn't show anything, so I went with the aspect route and found several places were our code wasn't threadsafe, but nothing showed up in the area with the document.

Comment: Sorry it didn't pan out; I'll defer to @StanislavL about your `UndoableEditEvent` handler.

Answer (score 0):

You must add the Change events to the UndoManager. In opposite case Document structure is changed but you try to undo with old structure. You can merge multiple UndoableEdits in one see java-sl.com/tip_merge_undo_edits.html

Comment: Sorry, the code wasn't written clearly, I'll update it since undo is actually the undoManager.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out a solution of adding a timer to the update of the syntax highlighting that was being applied to the text box after an edit. If the text box is updated within a 200ms timer, the update is queued and applied after the syntax highlighting occurs.