# How to append StringBuilder to textarea while replacing the previous string builder that was there?

Tags: java, swing, append, jtextarea, stringbuilder

So `string.append` and `string2.append` are `StringBuilder` objects I made to load words from a text file faster, my problem is that when I switch from radio button occurrence and alphabetical it just adds to the text area instead of replacing the previous list. Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
for(SuperString word : ss)
{
  count++;
  string.append(Integer.toString(count)+ "       "+ word+ "\n");
  string.toString();
}
if(occurrence.isSelected())
{
 textarea.setText("");
 textarea.append("    "+filename+" has wordcount: "+words.size()+
  "\n-------------------------\n\n");
 textarea.append(string.toString());
}


 for(SuperString word : ss2)
{
   count2++;
   string2.append(Integer.toString(count2)+ "       "+ word.toString()+ "\n");  
}
     if(alphabetical.isSelected())
{
  textarea.setText("");
  textarea.append(string2.toString());

}
```

Comment: `"when I switch from radiobutton occurrence and alphabetical"` -- consider explaining this as if we don't already know what your program is doing or is supposed to be doing. e.g., what in blazes is "radiobutton occurence"?

Comment: When I click on occurence my StringBuilder (string) appends to textarea that has presorted the txt file by occurence of words, when I click alphabetical my StringBuilder (string2) appends to textarea that has been presorted by alphebtical strings of the txt file.. when I do this as is it just adds to the text area instead of replacing what's there, i.e. making the list longer and longer

Comment: Oh sorry, JRadioButton is like a clickable 'type' I guess. so based on which is selected a certain list will be displayed

Comment: Maybe it's me, but I'm totally lost. Please consider creating and posting a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), a small but complete program that only has necessary code to demonstrate your problem, that we can copy, paste, compile and run without modification.

Comment: Maybe `textarea.replaceRange()`

Comment: There are several classes and to implement my driver class...

Basically I need my textarea to reset each time I select occurrence or alphabetical BUT it is not doing so even though I have a textarea.setText("") command in each instance of isSelected(); ......Does that make more sense?

Comment: Nahh, that's not working.. like replaceRange("",0,0)  ..it requires a string, int , int

Answer (score 2):

You may be looking for [`replaceRange()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#replaceRange-java.lang.String-int-int-), which "Simply does a delete if the new string is null or empty." Then you can [`insert()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#insert-java.lang.String-int-) the new text at position `0`.

```
textarea.replaceRange(null, 0, 0);
textarea.insert(string2.toString(), 0);
```

Addendum: *This above does not work*.

Both `replaceRange()` and `setText()` correctly clear the text area when supplied with a `null` or empty `String`. The latter is illustrated in this complete [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20603012/230513). As you may have a problem elsewhere in your code, verify that *all* Swing GUI objects are constructed and manipulated *only* on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). Note in particular that `append()` is [no longer thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15979112/230513).

Comment: I just want to clear and replace the textarea, appreantly this is hard to to using stringbuilder. this above does not work

Comment: I've elaborated above. If you still have a problem, please edit your question to include a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the problem.